"Only once" vs "Always ask" on opening coordinates with Android app
Is there an API for opening coordinates in Android which would show the default? Something like:

Open with this app: "only once" vs "always" dialog which would show you all the applications on the phone which can handle such intent?

I'm talking about this one:

Right now I do it like this:
fun startNavigation() {
    
            val data = intent.getSerializableExtra(CheckInStartActivity.KEY_DATA) as Data
            val location = data.location as Location
    
            val latitude = location.lat
            val longitude = location.lng
    
            val uriWaze = Uri.parse("https://waze.com/ul?ll=$latitude,$longitude&navigate=yes")
            val intentWaze = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriWaze)
            intentWaze.setPackage("com.waze")
    
            val uriGoogle = "google.navigation:q=$latitude,$longitude"
            val intentGoogleNav = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uriGoogle))
            intentGoogleNav.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps")
    
            val title = getString(R.string.choose_navigation_app)
            val chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intentGoogleNav, title)
            val arr = arrayOfNulls<Intent>(1)
            arr[0] = intentWaze
    
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, arr)
            startActivity(chooserIntent)
        }

but this solution:

does not generalize for all apps that can handle coordinates
does not ask the user whether they would like to always use this app or only once

Is there a general way/API to do such thing? Or is this coded for each application one by one on the screenshot I linked with the buttons and everything manually?

So, do you want to directly open Waze app while calling startNavigation function without any popup like you are getting in the screenshot attached?

"does not generalize for all apps that can handle coordinates" -- did you try just using a geo: Uri with ACTION_VIEW, as is covered in the documentation? "does not ask the user whether they would like to always use this app or only once" -- I do not know if you will get that if you use EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS. Also bear in mind that the behavior may vary by OS version and device manufacturer.
